# Flask: BuildError(endpoint, values, method, self) while specifying a hyperlink to rediirect to another page

Tags: python, flask

Here is my project structure.

```
Auth-Test
    |---static
        |---js
        |---css
        |---img
    |---templates
        |-authz.html
        |-home.html
        |-ssohistory.html

    |-AuthzTests.py
```

Here is my application code:

```
@app.route('/')
def index():    
    return render_template('home.html')

@app.route('/authz')
def authzTest():
    return render_template('authz.html', async_mode=socketio.async_mode)


@app.route('/ssohistory',methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def ssoHistory():
    form = ssoHistData(form_name='selectPeriod')
    form.logFrom.choices = [(row.id, row.loginTime) for row in 
    formSession.query(SsoData).all()]
    form.logTo.choices = [(row.id, row.loginTime) for row in 
    formSession.query(SsoData).all()]
    formSession.close()

    if request.method == 'GET':
        return render_template('ssohistory.html', form=form)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        #lots of code

    return '', 204
```

I can access my application's webpage  with:

```
127.0.0.1:5000/
127.0.0.1:5000/authz
127.0.0.1:5000/ssohistory
```

And one of the templates html:

```
$ cat authz.html

<div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div id="containerX" ></div>  -------> Here the data is written whatever is performed in authzTest() function.
            </div>
</div>
```

Upto this the application works fine. But I want a hyperlink in the page which redirects it to ssohistory.html page. But the moment I add it as below I get the error.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class=text-center col-md-4>
        <p><a href="{{ url_for('.ssohistory') }}">Historical Test Data</a></p>    ----> The moment I add this to redirect the page to ssohistory.html I start getting the error.
    </div>
</div>
```

The Error Details:

```
[2018-02-07 12:16:36,377] ERROR in app: Exception on /authz [GET]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1982, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1614, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1517, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1612, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1598, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "C:/Users/smrutim/Documents/Projects/MyPrograms/Python/vpxd-svc/Auth-Test/AuthzTests.py", line 186, in authzTest
    return render_template('authz.html', async_mode=socketio.async_mode)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\flask\templating.py", line 134, in render_template
    context, ctx.app)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\flask\templating.py", line 116, in _render
    rv = template.render(context)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\jinja2\environment.py", line 1008, in render
    return self.environment.handle_exception(exc_info, True)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\jinja2\environment.py", line 780, in handle_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "C:\Users\smrutim\Documents\Projects\MyPrograms\Python\vpxd-svc\Auth-Test\templates\authz.html", line 161, in top-level template code
    <p><a href="{{ url_for('.ssohistory') }}">Historical Test Data</a></p>
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\flask\helpers.py", line 333, in url_for
    return appctx.app.handle_url_build_error(error, endpoint, values)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1805, in handle_url_build_error
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\flask\helpers.py", line 323, in url_for
    force_external=external)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\werkzeug\routing.py", line 1776, in build
    raise BuildError(endpoint, values, method, self)
BuildError: Could not build url for endpoint 'ssohistory'. Did you mean 'ssoHistory' instead?
```

Comment: Try looking into `C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\werkzeug\routing.py` and see if you can change 'ssohistory' to 'ssoHistory' like the error says

Comment: ssohistory is my html file and the route.

Comment: I am not sure from where it is picking up 'ssoHistory' (in camel case)  in the stack trace. There is no file, variable named as such.